# Adding a View to Framelayout doesn't display

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-framelayout

> I am trying to create a custom **FrameLayout that contains a Button and an ImageButton** . It's xml  is

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tab_btn_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/viewed_sep_bg_border"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Video"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/tab_tick_one"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/slanted_tick_green"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

I want one layout with this `button` and `ImageButton`.So I created a Custom `FrameLayout` but it isn't showing anything. Only occupying space.

```
public class TabFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private TabFrameLayout mTabFrameLayout;
    private Button txtButton;
    private ImageButton ibTick;

    public TabFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public TabFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public TabFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        mTabFrameLayout = this;

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frageParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        mTabFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(frageParams);

        setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        txtButton = new Button(context);
        txtButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        txtButton.setTextSize(24);
        txtButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txtButton.setText("txtButton");
        txtButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.viewed_sep_bg_border);

        LayoutParams buttonParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        txtButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

        ibTick = new ImageButton(context);
        ibTick.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        ibTick.setImageResource(R.drawable.slanted_tick_green);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) ibTick.getLayoutParams();
        //params.setLayoutDirection(L);
        params.height = 50;
        params.width = 50;
        params.setMargins(0, -4, -4, 0);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;

        //params.weight = 1.0f;
        //params.
        ibTick.setLayoutParams(params);


        mTabFrameLayout.addView(txtButton);
        mTabFrameLayout.addView(ibTick);
        mTabFrameLayout.invalidate();


        /*RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)txtButton.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);*/
        //params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);


    }
}
```

I have added `ImageButton` and Button to `FrameLayout` but doesn't show. And how could I give `layout_weight = 1` to this `FrameLayout` .

Comment: Instead of `FrameLayout` use `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: But if one work can be done by FrameLayout why use a heavier layout like RelativeLayout. There must be a way.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a linear layout within frame layout  and the add layout weight to it which would solve your problem.

Comment: It is an overhead . The above layout is for a tab button and I have to add them programmatically to LinearLayout. And if something is done via xml. It must be created via programmatically.And thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Then i think it is better to create a linear layout programmatically and assign weight.

Comment: No it have same performance. And I think doing it programmatically takes much time than doing it via xml

Answer (score 0):

You need `setLayoutParams` before set their properties. This is because the parent of the Views that needs to know what size to allocate to the Views.

```
     //Create Button
     txtButton = new Button(context);
     LayoutParams buttonParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     txtButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
     txtButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     txtButton.setTextSize(24);
      ......
     //Create ImageView
     ibTick = new ImageButton(context);
     LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     ibTick.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
     ibTick.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
         .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The `layout_weight` will work only if its parent is `LinearLayout`. In your case, weight is not working, and you have set the width to `0 dp` which is making the view invisible.

Changing `android:layout_width` to `wrap_content` will display the view.

Hope this helps.